# int' object has no attribute 'split' for requests_ntlm

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a simple program to login to internal website, however I'm getting below error

Error

```
path/Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests_ntlm\requests_ntlm.py, line 34, in __init_ 
    self.domain, self.username = username.split('\\', 1)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

**Code**

```
import getpass
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

url='https://abc.[com]'
user=<username>
r=requests.get(url)
r=requests.get(url,HttpNtlmAuth(user,getpass.getpass()))
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: The error seems to be connected with the value of `user`, could You share an example value that You're using?

Comment: the username is all numeric value e.g. 12345

Comment: So here's the problem, as @d-malan wrote, it's expected to have a string in format `domain\username`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks the the `username` you're using is an integer, but the [requests-ntlm3 documentation](https://pypi.org/project/requests-ntlm3/) says it must be a string in the format `'domain\\username'`

Comment: Thanks Guys, it's working now, I forgot to add the 'auth' parameter.
'code'
r=requests.get(url,auth=HttpNtlmAuth(user,getpass.getpass()))